# Free video podcasts/tutorials for Java beginner

Tags: java, podcast

What are some video tutorials/podcasts for Java and J2ME?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stanford's YouTube channel has a very good introductory course on Java:

*[Programming Methodology (CS106A)](http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=84A56BC7F4A1F852)*

Other video tutorials

- http://www.javaomatic.com/
- http://www.javavideotutes.com/index/lessons/

Answer (score 6):

I generally found the podcasts [Parley's](http://www.parleys.com/display/PARLEYS/Home) or [InfoQ](http://www.infoq.com/) to be helpful. Anything from Joshua Bloch or Neal Gafter (even though they disagree about closures) to be of top notch quality.

Comment: I'm a big Josh Bloch fan too, but his material is not for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen one that is oriented towards just "Teaching Java", but I think it's a great idea.

After you evaluate the answers here, please post what meets your needs and what is missing. I've always thought it would be fun to do a video podcast where you start with simple syntax and go through OO design, refactoring, patterns, etc. Basically just teach core Java in a podcast.

If that's what you are after and you don't find it, be sure to reply to this message. This is the one podcast I've considered doing--and I've been thinking about doing it for years, I just wasn't sure it would be of value.

If you are after general Java information--JavaPossee rocks.

Comment: Yes it would be great if you could make free tutorial videos from starting JAVA practically for a beginner.